# SemaphoreSlim Not Preventing Async Race Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, semaphore

I am currently using a SemaphoreSlim lock to prevent an async race condition, however I'm noticing on the production server this is not being prevented. I've tried testing locally and haven't been able to reproduce the issue (seems to be working properly). I noticed the issue when I updated the server code from synchronous to asynchronous. From the documentation I've read asynchronous code should be supported.

```
private static SemaphoreSlim m_AssignUniqueBookingKey = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 1, maxCount: 1);
public async Task CreateForInstance(visitP)
{
  string unique_booking_key = null;
  await m_AssignUniqueBookingKey.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
   unique_booking_key = await UniqueBookingKeyCommand.UpdateForVisit(visitP.ID);
  }
 finally
 {
  m_AssignUniqueBookingKey.Release();
 }
```

Comment: What race condition exactly is being prevented?

Comment: Do you want exactly one thread per time being able to execute the code `unique_booking_key = await UniqueBookingKeyCommand.UpdateForVisit(visitP.ID);` ?

Comment: I'm also wondering whether your race condition is on an external resource (e.g. database), and you have multiple AppDomains / application instances (each of which will have its own `SemaphoreSlim`)

Comment: This code does not appear to be the problem in and of itself. Merely providing exclusion is not necessarily enough to make a semantics-preserving transition from synchronous to asynchronous code -- how do you verify the code is not working, and how have you verified that is due to parallel calls to `UniqueBookingKeyCommand.UpdateForVisit`, and not the semantics of that call or how the results are used?

Comment: I noticed duplicate keys were being assigned to multiple visits. When checking the timestamps in the DB I confirmed that the visits were updated at the same time (Only visits affected shared the same timestamp as another visit with the same key). I confirmed the application is only running one w3wp process as I've read this can cause issues. I also don't believe there is any issue with the code itself. I created an endpoint for testing locally which runs UpdateForVisit in parallel and when run with SemaphoreSlim it was working as expected (no duplicates).

Comment: If this code ultimately defers to a database, consider fixing the issue of atomicity there, with a proper locking strategy using transactions and an appropriate isolation level (`BEGIN TRANSACTION; UPDATE x WITH (HOLDLOCK) WHERE ...; IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0) INSERT ...` This would ensure clients can't produce inconsistent data even if they're not carefully written for mutual exclusion (or if multiple independent clients run concurrently), which is a nice assumption to have available.